# How to unlist given list in python?

Tags: python

I have to copy particular columns from a given file to another file. but while copying that columns to another file i don't need them in list format. How can i do that?

eg suppose file is `abc.txt.gz`

```
bit address  data                                        code  new
 
0   0FA34B   0002623748594759834784648294918748734610484 123   00000001

1   AB102C   2814699837426459814735985739460746706706600 124   00000002

1   C102BC   1237748798359846709648378598089837658736738 125   00000003
```

From this data i needed to copy 3rd and 4th column and move to another file.

Expected output: `data.txt`

In expected output I only need data & new. I don't want nothing else to get copied to my new file.
Example:

```
0002623748594759834784648294918748734610484 00000001

2814699837426459814735985739460746706706600 00000002

1237748798359846709648378598089837658736738 00000003
```

This is my current attempt:

```py
for l in fin:
    if l.strip("\n '"):
        column = l.split(" ")
        fout.write("%s %s \n" % (column[3:4], column[4:5]))
```

Current output:

```
--name of file

--data of file

[] []

['']

['']

['0002623748594759834784648294918748734610484'] ['00000001']

['2814699837426459814735985739460746706706600'] ['00000002']

['1237748798359846709648378598089837658736738'] ['00000003']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Think carefully about what `column[3:4]` means. Do you want a list here? Why or why not? (Hint: what happens if you write `([1], [2])`? Does that put the elements of the list together into a new list? Or does it instead create a tuple with the two lists? Now, which one do you want, in order to use `%` with a string?) Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to think about the program logic carefully before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
       columns = l.split(" ")
       if len(columns) == 5: # validate line that it has exactly 5 columns
           fout.write("%s %s \n" % (columns[3], columns[4]))
```

Comment: probably you have more/less than 5 columns in the file, try with ```if len(columns) >= 5:```

Comment: but now only problem is  current output:

--name of file

--data of file



these are also getting copied. how can i remove this.  i tried striping it out. but it's not working

Comment: @avs: then there must be extra code that you're not showing. Please edit the question to show all the relevant code.